# django UpdateView not saving form

Tags: django, forms, django-class-based-views

All my CreateViews are working fine, but this one is not (although this is UpdateView).  After checking, trying to identify differences, I find none.  Must be something I'm still missing.

Template:

```
<form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.non_field_errors }}
        {{ form.errors }}
        {{ form.make }}
        {{ form.make.errors }}
        {{ form.model}}
        {{ form.model.errors }}
        {{ form.year}}
        {{ form.year.errors }}

            <button type="submit"> Save</button>
            <a href="javascript:close_window();"> Close</a>
    </form>
```

Url paterns in URLS.py:

```
url(r'^update/(?P<pk>\w+)/$',UpdateView.as_view(
    model=Vehicles,
    form_class=VehiclesForm,
    success_url="/main/",
    template_name="vehicle_detail.html")),
```

Model:

```
from django.db import models


class Vehicles(models.Model):
    stock = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False, db_index=True)
    vin = models.CharField(max_length=17, blank=False, db_index=True)
    vinlast8 = models.CharField(max_length=8, blank=False, db_index=True)
    make = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=False)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=False)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=4, blank=False)
    deal = models.IntegerField(blank=False, db_index=True, null=True)
    sold = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)
    origin = models.ForeignKey('origins.Origins', db_column='origin')
    #origin = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    bank = models.ForeignKey('banks.Banks', db_column='bank', null=True)
    vehtype = models.ForeignKey('vehtypes.Vehtypes', db_column='vehtype', verbose_name='Veh Type')
    status = models.ForeignKey('status.Status', db_column='status')
    imported = models.DateField()
    clerk = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False, db_index=True, verbose_name='Clerk')
    completed = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    registry = models.IntegerField(blank=True, verbose_name='Reg #', null=True)
    plate = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=10)
    tagno = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Tag #')
    tag_exp = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Tag Exp')
    unit_linked = models.IntegerField(blank=False, verbose_name='Link')
    salesperson = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, verbose_name='S/person', null=True)
    agent = models.ForeignKey('agents.Agents', db_column='agent', blank=True, null=True)
    tradein1 = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='stock')
    tr1vin = models.CharField(max_length=17, blank=True, db_index=True, null=True, verbose_name='vin')
    tr1make = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='make')
    tr1model = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='model')
    tr1year = models.CharField(max_length=4, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='year')
    tradein2 = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='stock')
    tr2vin = models.CharField(max_length=17, blank=True, db_index=True, null=True,verbose_name='vin')
    tr2make = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True,verbose_name='make')
    tr2model = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True,verbose_name='model')
    tr2year = models.CharField(max_length=4, blank=True, null=True,verbose_name='year')
    lhtrade1 = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='L/holder')
    lh1docreq = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='D/Requested')
    lh1docrec = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='D/Received')
    lhtrade2 = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='L/holder')
    lh2docreq = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='D/Requested')
    lh2docrec = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='D/Received')

    cust1name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, db_index=True, null=True,
                                     verbose_name='name')
    cust1lic = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, db_index=True, null=True,
                                verbose_name='license')
    cust1addr = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='address')
    cust1city = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='city')
    cust1state = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='state')
    cust1zip = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='zipcode')
    cust1email = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='email')
    cust1tel1 = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, verbose_name='Tel. 1', null=True)
    cust1tel2 = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, verbose_name='Tel. 2', null=True)
    cust1ssn = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True, db_index=True, null=True,verbose_name='SSN')

    cust2name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, db_index=True, null=True,
                                     verbose_name='name')
    cust2lic = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, db_index=True, null=True,
                                verbose_name='license')
    cust2addr = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='address')
    cust2city = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='city')
    cust2state = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='state')
    cust2zip = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='zipcode')
    cust2email = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='email')
    cust2tel1 = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, verbose_name='Tel. 1', null=True)
    cust2tel2 = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, verbose_name='Tel. 2', null=True)
    cust2ssn = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True, db_index=True, null=True,verbose_name='SSN')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'vehicles'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.stock

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.stock = self.stock.upper()

        return super(Vehicles, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Form:

```
from django import forms
from models import Vehicles


class VehiclesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Vehicles
```

It's a modelform.  Firebug and console do report the POST is actually occuring, but record is not updated.

Appreciate anything you realize it's wrong.

Comment: Does it redirect to `success_url` but hasn't saved the object? or it re-displays the form?  You should output the form errors in your template, probably there's a validation error

Comment: It only re-displays the form.  form errors were added to edited question.

Comment: so, do you see any errors?

Comment: Sorry, I should *also* indicated there were no errors.

Comment: @Anentropic, I just added {{form.errors}} and noticed that when posting, it lists all required field.  Just to clear this out, all of the fields (at least the required ones) are in the original version of the template.  When the template is first rendered, all required fields are indeed populated.  I am wondering if maybe since some of the required fields, it's requiring an instance, not the current value.  Just a thought.

Comment: can you paste your `Vehicles` and `VehiclesForm` classes

Comment: @Anentropic, added model & form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since, there is no answer...

At first, since you don't modify in any way your form you don't to specify it - ModelForm is implicitly meant in UpdateView by default. So, you don't need this:

```
form_class=VehiclesForm
```

Then, in your model (which is huge) you don't need `blank=False` - it's also defaults.

Your problem, I think, is in field validation procedure. Your template html-form renders only some of fields, but your model has much more (and what is important - they aren't optional and they have no default values).
Because of this, you simply don't see validation errors.

if you render whole form like this:

```
<form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}

    {{ form.as_p }}

    <button type="submit"> Save</button>
    <a href="javascript:close_window();"> Close</a>
</form>
```

...you'll see validation errors!

*PS:* If you wanted to render only those fields you must:

1) specify `fields` attribute with list of those fields:

```
# django doc example    
class AuthorUpdate(UpdateView):
        model = Author
        fields = ['name']
        template_name_suffix = '_update_form'
```

2) ensure that you provide all needful data (default or explicitly through form fields) for model instance saving.

3) read the Django docs - it is very detailed and meticulous, good luck!

Comment: Mine does not save, I tap submit, and still the same as before.

Answer (score 0):

For me I have to change

```
<form action="." .....>
```

to

```
<form action="" ..... >
```